# Какая система будет восстановлена при сбросе до заводских настроек: Windows 7 или 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Имеется компьютер на Windows 10, обновлённый с Windows 7. Мне интересно, какая система будет восстановлена при сбросе до заводских настроек: Windows 7 или 10? И надо ли будет вводить ключ активации, если система уже была активирована?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У меня так же, с лицензии 7ки обновился до 10ки. При при сбросе до заводских настроек устанавливается чистая Windows 10. Для отката до 7ки есть отдельный пункт.

Год назад ставил систему с нуля, 10ку, использовал ключ от 7ки.

Comment: Пункта сброса до семёрки не видел, где он находится?

Comment: У меня его нет сейчас, раньше был, это когда с 7ки обновляешь 10ку, есть откат системы, давно его не видел, так как 7й года 2 не пользовался. А так сброс до чистой виндовс 10 тут - «Пуск» - «Параметры» - «Обновление и безопасность» - «Восстановление». (Раньше если не ошибаюсь тут был пункт отката на 7, но сейчас нет поддержки 7ки так что смысла в этом нет)

Comment: Я так понял, что ключ не понадобится?

Comment: С чистой установки как то раз просил (я помню с коробки Виндовс 7 вводил ключ и его приняли), но у меня ключ привязан к учетке, так что не просит при откате до чистой системы. Год назад последний раз откатывал.